# Docker on Mac: how to test for listen port in container

Tags: macos, docker, port, forwarding

I recently installed Docker native on Mac, switching over from docker-machine. I have a container with Zookeeper, which opens a port on 2181. This process can take some 10-15 seconds however.

Previously with docker-machine I used to check whether Zookeeper had started listening on the port using netcat:

```
nc -z 192.168.99.100 2181
```

Netcat returns non-zero exit code while Zookeeper is starting up and as soon as it's done, the connection succeeds and netcat returns zero.

In Docker Mac-native however, the connection always succeeds when the container is present, but during Zookeeper startup it drops the connection immediately. When Zookeeper is ready it keeps the connection open. Netcat does not see this difference and "nc -z" always returns zero.

So my question is: is there an easy way to check from outside of the container whether Zookeeper has actually started listening on the port?

Answer (score 1):

If you are just checking wanna check manually , You can use telnet.

Command:

```
telnet localhost 80
```

Output:

```
Trying ::1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

This means that the connection was successful. The Command Usage:

```
telnet <address> <port>
```

Please note that you can only use telnet for TCP ports.

Another way would be checking the service from the container with `docker exec` :

```
docker exec <container name> "echo stat | nc <zookeeper ip> 2181"
docker exec <container name> "bash path/to/zkServer.sh status"
```

Comment: telnet works the same as netcat here. It also gets a valid connection, but as soon as the connection is established, docker drops it since Zookeeper is not listening yet. Once Zookeeper has started, the connection remains open after establishing.